# Count weighted integer compositions

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, integer-sequences

What is the asymptotic growth of the sequence
$$a_n:=\sum_{k\geq 0} 3^k c_{n,k},$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $c_{n,k}$ denotes the number of integer compositions of $n$ with exactly $k$ many 2s?

A composition of $n$ is a sum $n=c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_p$, with all the $c_i$ positive.
The first values of the sequence $a_n$ are $1,1,4,8,22,52,135,\ldots$ (not in the OEIS). [Edit: As pointed out by Somos below, the value 135 is wrong, and must be corrected to 132, and then the sequence is in the OEIS.]

So far, I was only able to prove the following bounds: As $\sum_{k\geq 0}c_{n,k}=2^{n-1}$, it follows that
$$2^{n-1}\leq a_n \leq (2\sqrt{3})^n=(3.464...)^n.$$

Comment: Can we say $c_{n,k}=c_{n-2,k-1}k+1)$, and thus produce a recursion?

Comment: $c_{n,k}$ is the sequence [A105114](https://oeis.org/A105114) in the OEIS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When corrected, $a_n$ is the [OEIS sequence A052528](https://oeis.org/A052528) whose first nine values are
 $\,1,1,4,8,22,52,132,324,808,\dots\,$ and it has a linear recurrence.

The combinatorial recurrence from its combination definition leads immediately to
$$ a_n = 2a_{n-2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k $$
where the $\, 2a_{n-2}\,$ comes from the combination part $2.$ 
The ordinary generating function is
$$ (1 - x)/(1 - 2 x - 2 x^2 + 2 x^3). $$
The growth rate of $\,a_n\,$ depends on the reciprocal of the smallest root
 $\,\alpha\,$ of $\, 2x^3 -2x^2 -2x +1.$ Thus
$\,1/\alpha \approx 2.4811943\,$ so that $\,a_n \propto 1/\alpha^n.$

**EDIT**: The sequence $\,c_{n,k}\,$ is the triangular [OEIS sequence A105114](https://oeis.org/A105114)

> Triangle read by rows: T(n,k) is the number of compositions of n having exactly k parts equal to 2.

Again, its combination definition leads immediately to $$ c_{n,k} = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{n-j,k-[j=2]} $$
where $\,[j=2] := 1\,$ if $j=2$, else $0$.

Comment: I think there is also a multiplied constant, the limit of $(1-x/\alpha)\,\mathrm{gf}(x)$ as $x\to\alpha$, which is about 0.56158611.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Yes, I really meant $\propto$ instead of $\sim$. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! The one mistake in computations I made with 135 instead of 132 spoiled my OEIS search. After entering 1,1,4,8,22,52, there were still several sequences matching, and then after entering 135, none was left.